# Creating a custom MCE view for your shortcodes

Tags: tinymce, views

How to create a custom MCE view of my own WordPress shortcode?

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: If this is no question, but sharing knowledge, then please file an [edit] and move the "answer" part to a real answer. Thank you for doing so.

Comment: my bad - all fixed!

Answer (score 12):

I had a lot of trouble finding information and examples of this, so here you go:

https://github.com/dtbaker/wordpress-mce-view-and-shortcode-editor

This converts a `[shortcode]` into a nice custom view to match the frontend, and adds an edit button for easy shortcode editing.

[image: clicking on a wordpress shortcode view]

```
<?php

/**
 * Class dtbaker_Shortcode_Banner
 * handles the creation of [boutique_banner] shortcode
 * adds a button in MCE editor allowing easy creation of shortcode
 * creates a wordpress view representing this shortcode in the editor
 * edit/delete button on wp view as well makes for easy shortcode managements.
 *
 * separate css is in style.content.css - this is loaded in frontend and also backend with add_editor_style
 *
 * Author: dtbaker@gmail.com
 * Copyright 2014
 */

class dtbaker_Shortcode_Banner {
    private static $instance = null;
    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( ! self::$instance )
            self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function init(){
        // comment this 'add_action' out to disable shortcode backend mce view feature
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'init_plugin' ), 20 );
        add_shortcode('boutique_banner', array($this,'dtbaker_shortcode_banner'));
    }
    public function init_plugin() {
        add_action( 'print_media_templates', array( $this, 'print_media_templates' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( $this, 'admin_print_footer_scripts' ), 100 );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_dtbaker_mce_banner_button', array( $this, 'wp_ajax_dtbaker_mce_banner_button' ) );
        if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') || current_user_can('edit_pages') ){
            add_filter("mce_external_plugins", array($this, 'mce_plugin'));
            add_filter("mce_buttons", array($this, 'mce_button'));
        }
    }
    // front end shortcode displaying:
    public function dtbaker_shortcode_banner($atts=array(), $innercontent='', $code='') {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'id' => false,
            'title' => 'Special:',
            'link' => '',
            'linkhref' => '',
        ), $atts));

        $banner_id = strtolower(preg_replace('#\W+#','',$title));

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="full_banner" id="banner_<?php echo $banner_id;?>">
            <span class="title"><?php echo $title;?></span>
            <span class="content"><?php echo $innercontent;?></span>
            <?php if($link && $linkhref){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $linkhref;?>" class="link dtbaker_button_light"><?php echo $link;?></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function wp_ajax_dtbaker_mce_banner_button(){
        header("Content-type: text/javascript");
        ?>
        ( function() {
            tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'dtbaker_mce_banner', function( editor, url ) {
                editor.addButton( 'dtbaker_mce_banner_button', {
                    text: 'Banner',
                    icon: false,
                    onclick: function() {
                        wp.mce.boutique_banner.popupwindow(editor);
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } )();
        <?php
        die();
    }
    public function mce_plugin($plugin_array){
        $plugin_array['dtbaker_mce_banner'] = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=dtbaker_mce_banner_button');
        return $plugin_array;
    }
    public function mce_button($buttons){
        array_push($buttons, 'dtbaker_mce_banner_button');
        return $buttons;
    }
    /**
     * Outputs the view inside the wordpress editor.
     */
    public function print_media_templates() {
        if ( ! isset( get_current_screen()->id ) || get_current_screen()->base != 'post' )
            return;
        ?>
        <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-editor-boutique-banner">
            <div class="boutique_banner_{{ data.type }}"></div>
            <div class="full_banner" id="banner_{{ data.id }}">
                <span class="title">{{ data.title }}</span>
                <span class="content">{{ data.innercontent }}</span>
                <# if ( data.link ) { #>
                    <# if ( data.linkhref ) { #>
                        <a href="{{ data.linkhref }}" class="link dtbaker_button_light">{{ data.link }}</a>
                    <# } #>
                <# } #>
            </div>
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    public function admin_print_footer_scripts() {
        if ( ! isset( get_current_screen()->id ) || get_current_screen()->base != 'post' )
            return;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                var media = wp.media, shortcode_string = 'boutique_banner';
                wp.mce = wp.mce || {};
                wp.mce.boutique_banner = {
                    shortcode_data: {},
                    View: {
                        template: media.template( 'editor-boutique-banner' ),
                        postID: $('#post_ID').val(),
                        initialize: function( options ) {
                            this.shortcode = options.shortcode;
                            wp.mce.boutique_banner.shortcode_data = this.shortcode;

                        },
                        getHtml: function() {
                            var options = this.shortcode.attrs.named;
                            options['innercontent'] = this.shortcode.content;
                            return this.template(options);
                        }
                    },
                    edit: function( node ) {
                        var data = window.decodeURIComponent( $( node ).attr('data-wpview-text') );
                        console.debug(this);
                        var values = this.shortcode_data.attrs.named;
                        values['innercontent'] = this.shortcode_data.content;
                        console.log(values);

                        wp.mce.boutique_banner.popupwindow(tinyMCE.activeEditor, values);
                        //$( node ).attr( 'data-wpview-text', window.encodeURIComponent( shortcode ) );
                    },
                    // this is called from our tinymce plugin, also can call from our "edit" function above
                    // wp.mce.boutique_banner.popupwindow(tinyMCE.activeEditor, "bird");
                    popupwindow: function(editor, values, onsubmit_callback){
                        if(typeof onsubmit_callback != 'function'){
                            onsubmit_callback = function( e ) {
                                // Insert content when the window form is submitted (this also replaces during edit, handy!)
                                var s = '[' + shortcode_string;
                                for(var i in e.data){
                                    if(e.data.hasOwnProperty(i) && i != 'innercontent'){
                                        s += ' ' + i + '="' + e.data[i] + '"';
                                    }
                                }
                                s += ']';
                                if(typeof e.data.innercontent != 'undefined'){
                                    s += e.data.innercontent;
                                    s += '[/' + shortcode_string + ']';
                                }
                                editor.insertContent( s );
                            };
                        }
                        editor.windowManager.open( {
                            title: 'Banner',
                            body: [
                                {
                                    type: 'textbox',
                                    name: 'title',
                                    label: 'Title',
                                    value: values['title']
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'textbox',
                                    name: 'link',
                                    label: 'Button Text',
                                    value: values['link']
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'textbox',
                                    name: 'linkhref',
                                    label: 'Button URL',
                                    value: values['linkhref']
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'textbox',
                                    name: 'innercontent',
                                    label: 'Content',
                                    value: values['innercontent']
                                }
                            ],
                            onsubmit: onsubmit_callback
                        } );
                    }
                };
                wp.mce.views.register( shortcode_string, wp.mce.boutique_banner );
            }(jQuery));
        </script>

        <?php
    }
}

dtbaker_Shortcode_Banner::get_instance()->init();
```

Comment: The printed shortcode (print_media_templates) no longer works for me, it just shows a loading element that keeps on loading. Clicking the edit pencil does nothing. Console says: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [myshortcode myvar="300"]

Comment: if i dont add the myvar it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'named' of undefined

Comment: Thanks sir, it's quite hard but and the end I did it.

Comment: This exceptionally good example does not work with WP 4.5.x. Any possibilities to update @dtbaker?